# Reactjs - Ordering div when resized

Tags: html, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am using `reactstrap` to build my webapp.

So I have 2 `Jumbotrons` aligned in the following way:

```
<Row>
    <Col md='9' id='bigger-block'>
        <Jumbotron>Block 1</Jumbotron>
    </Col>
    <Col md='3' id='smaller-block'>
        <Jumbotron>Block 2</Jumbotron>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

So, **bigger-block** covers 70% of the width positioned to left and **smaller-block** covers the remaining 30% to the right.

What I want to achieve is when the browser's width is reduced:

- **smaller-block** should go on top of **bigger-block**
- Both the blocks should now have full width (100% width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by adding some extra rules to your CSS.

reactstrap's grid system is based on flexbox , so it's possible to achieve responsive ordering using the [`order` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order). I've run a local test using the updated markup in your question, and was able to responsivly re-order by adding the following CSS rule:

CSS:

```
/* the @media block to only apply if the device width is less than 768px wide. 
This means the following rules will typically only take effect on smaller devices like smartphones. 
You can adjust this px width as per your requirements */

@media (max-width: 768px) { 

    #smaller-block {

        /* the 'order' rule is part of flexbox. 
           We can use it here to cause the 'smaller-block' to be ordered before the 
           'larger-block' when viewed on a smaller device/screen */
        order:-1; 
    }
}
```

There are lots of useful resources online introducing media queries. Some notable ones that I find useful are:

- https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
- https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-create-media-queries-in-responsive-web-design/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work! I am also new to this `@media` CSS, any link to documentation?